# Create a matrix out of lists

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am a beginner in python and I want to create a matrix out of multiple lists that do not contain any strings. I have for example the lists:

`h=[x+y, r**2, x/r+y]` and
`g=[2x, 3x+y, r+y]`

and I want as a result a matrix

`M= [[x+y, r**2, x/r+y], [2x, 3x+y, r+y]]`

How can I combine the list so that each list becomes the line of the matrix? I dont want to write each line by hand since in my code the length of the lines can be longer, therefor I need something like `M=Matrix([h], [g])` but this does not work.

Comment: Can you confirm that x, y, r are defined as variable (with a int or float) prior to the list h and g?

Comment: It is normally easier to use something like numpy (an extension for python) which supports matrix mathematics than trying got write your own.

Comment: If `r`, `x` and `y` are `int` or `float` variables, you already provided the correct code to create a list of lists (which can be interpreted as matrix). `M= [[x+y, r**2, x/r+y], [2x, 3x+y, r+y]]` should just work fine, when you correct the little mistake that `2x` must actually be `2*x` and `3x+y` must be `3*x+y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended for any matrix computation you use numpy as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090771/10111013):

```
import numpy as np

h=[x+y, r**2, x/r+y]
g=[2*x, 3*x+y, r+y]

M = np.array([h, g])
```

However if you do want to represent your matrix in list format then:

```
h=[x+y, r**2, x/r+y]
g=[2*x, 3*x+y, r+y]

M = [h, g]
```

Should work fine. You do not need to put the `h` and `g` inside square brackets a second time since they are already lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
r=1
x=2
y=3
M = [[x+y, r**2, x/r+y], [2*x, 3*x+y, r+y]]
# [[5, 1, 5.0], [4, 9, 4]]
```

Please note that coming from you line of code I replaces `2x` with `2*x` and `3x+y` with `3*x+y`

Answer (score 0):

Python allows developers to implement matrices using the nested list. Lists can be created if you put all elements between '['  and ']'.

```
x= [[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9]]
    
y= [[1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
   [0,0,1]]

result = [[x[i][j] + y[i][j] for j in range(len(x[0]))] for i in range(len(x))]

print(result)
```

#### Output of the above program will be ### - [[2, 2, 3], [4, 6, 6], [7, 8, 10]]